# Movement of the Ribcage during movements of the Thoracic Spine

Tags: human-anatomy, computational-model, bio-mechanics, vertebra, spine

I want to find a rough relation between the angle of rotation of the thoracic spine and the corresponding segmental movements in the skeleton of the ribcage. I have come across some research which explains in detail the anatomy and axes of rotation for costovertebral and costotransverse joints.
I have also come across literature providing the movements of ribcage in the case of inhalation/exhalation.

However, I haven't found any literature that details the overall/partial movement of the thoracic wall or ribcage bones during thoracic movements. (flexion, side bending, axial rotation etc.) There is also a [previously asked unanswered question](https://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/85083/movement-of-the-thoracic-cage-during-movements-of-the-thoracic-spine) regarding this topic.

Can anyone suggest any previous work/paper/book/website that can provide me with a detailed kinematics of the thorax region?
Also, can the rotation/translation of ribcage bones be approximated if I know the angle and the axis of rotation of each thoracic vertebrae?